# If any locally constant sheaf on $X$ is constant, then $X$ is simply connected

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, representation-theory, homotopy-theory, sheaf-theory

I am having some trouble completing the proof of the following statement:

Let $X$ be a locally arcwise connected, connected topological space and suppose there exists an open covering stable by finite intersections by connected and simply connected subsets. If any locally constant sheaf on $X$ is constant, then $X$ is simply connected.

What I think I have understood from the proof of the notes I am following ($\textit{Algebra and Topology}$ by Pierre Schapira) is the next.

Firstly, we assume X is non empty and choose $x\in X$. Since $X$ is connected and locally arwise connected, it is arcwise connected and then the groupoid $\Pi_1(X)$ is equivalent to the category $\Pi_1(X,x)$ associated with the group $ \pi_1(X,x)$. That is, the category with one object $\{x\}$ and morphisms $\pi_1(X,x)$. Thus, the category $Fct(\Pi_1(X), \text{Mod}(k))$ is equivalent to $Fct(\Pi_1(X,x),\text{Mod}(k))$, and then to the category of representations $\text{Rep}(\pi_1(X,x), \text{Mod}(k))$, where $k$ denotes a commutative unitary ring. We also have that $\text{Mod}(k)$ is equivalent to $\text{Rep}(\{1\}, \text{Mod}(k))$ of trivial representations.

We are assuming that any locally constant sheaf on $X$ is constant. Therefore, we have the equality LCSH$(k_X)=$ CSH$(k_X)$. It is known that, if $X$ is non empty and connected, the category of constant sheaves CSH$(k_X)$ is equivalent to $\text{Mod}(k)$. From a previous theorem, thanks to the hypothesis made on $X$, LCSH$(k_X)$ is equivalent to $Fct(\Pi_1(X), \text{Mod}(k))$. Thus, we get an equivalence between the categories $Fct(\Pi_1(X), \text{Mod}(k))$ and $\text{Mod}(k)$.

Following all the equivalences, we find $\text{Rep}(\pi_1(X,x), \text{Mod}(k))$ is equivalent to $\text{Rep}(\{1\}, \text{Mod}(k))$.

From this I need to deduce that $\pi_1(X,x)$ is the trivial group with one element. I have tried to use the equivalence between them  but I don't get anything. In addition, I don't know if all the previous arguments are right.

Comment: You (more or less) obtained that two categories have equivalent categories of presheaves; is it true that they are themselves equivalent, at least when both are groups?

Comment: If I have understood it well, if your last statement is true, then it gives me the result I am looking for. But I am not able to prove it. Could you specify a little more please? (It is my first time studying category theory so it is a little hard for me)

Comment: In short, two categories having equivalent presheaf categories are themselves equivalent if they are [Cauchy complete](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cauchy+complete+category). Groups are Cauchy complete categories (the unique idempotent in a group is the identity).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Fosco Though note that “more or less” is significant here: the free $k$-linear category on $G$, which is $k[G]$, is not Cauchy complete as a $k$-Vect enriched category. One has to close under biproducts as well as retracts for this case, so that $G$ and $H$ have the same categories of representations when $k[G]$ and $k[H]$ have the same categories of finitely generated projectives, a difficult $K$-theory problem.

Comment: If the forgetful functor $U:G-Set\to Set$ is an equivalence of categories, $G \simeq Aut(U) \simeq Aut(id_{Set}) \simeq 1 $. If the fiber functor $F_x : LCS(X) \to Set$ is an equivalence then it follows $\pi_1(X,x) \simeq 1$ via Galois theory of covering spaces. Not sure but I think this is the way.

Comment: The Isos here are induced by the equivalences of categories.